# Can we use twitter4j.FilterQuery and twitter4j.RateLimitStatus in a same project

Tags: twitter, twitter4j

While doing a small application with Twitter Stream API and Twitter user search I have to use
twitter4j.FilterQuery and  twitter4j.RateLimitStatus classes.

These two classes are found in two different jar:

```
twitter4j-core-2.2.6.jar
twitter4j-core-3.0.3.jar
```

When I add these two classed into my class path i am getting the below exception:

```
Exception in thread "Twitter4J Async Dispatcher[0]" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: twitter4j.json.JSONObjectType.determine(Ltwitter4j/internal/org/json/JSONObject;)Ltwitter4j/json/JSONObjectType;
    at twitter4j.AbstractStreamImplementation$1.run(AbstractStreamImplementation.java:100)
    at twitter4j.internal.async.ExecuteThread.run(DispatcherImpl.java:116)
```

Please help me how to understand what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the latest version of twitter4j that is 3.0.5. It is reliable and working pretty good.