# CDH Twitter example Java error

Tags: java, twitter, bigdata, twitter4j, flume

I'm trying to follow the instructions from [CDH Twitter Example](https://github.com/cloudera/cdh-twitter-example) and get a problem similar to the one posed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21263974/can-we-use-twitter4j-filterquery-and-twitter4j-ratelimitstatus-in-a-same-project):

```
14/06/20 11:18:13 INFO twitter4j.TwitterStreamImpl: Establishing connection.
14/06/20 11:18:23 INFO twitter4j.TwitterStreamImpl: Connection established.
14/06/20 11:18:23 INFO twitter4j.TwitterStreamImpl: Receiving status stream.
Exception in thread "Twitter4J Async Dispatcher[0]" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:     twitter4j.json.JSONObjectType.determine(Ltwitter4j/internal/org/json/JSONObject;)Ltwitter4j    /json/JSONObjectType;
    at     twitter4j.AbstractStreamImplementation$1.run(AbstractStreamImplementation.java:100)
    at twitter4j.internal.async.ExecuteThread.run(DispatcherImpl.java:116)
```

The difference is that I only have `twitter4j-core-3.0.3.jar` (that is, I have no older versions of this file). 
The issue has been reported to the authour of the example on Git, but no solution was posted.
Does it exist, and what can I do to work around this problem? Should I rebuild some jars?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that a jar built with maven in accordance with the insturctions works fine, whereas the one that can be downloaded for some reason does not.

Answer (score 0):

Remove following jars from lib directory of flume installation and try again.
twitter4j-core-3.0.3.jar
twitter4j-media-support-3.0.3
twitter4j-stream-3.0.3

Answer (score 0):

After removing twitter related jars from flume/lib it worked.